# What skill does using a Molotov cocktail fall under?

Tags: dresden-files

I think it would be safe to say that some form of craftsmanship skill roll is required for Molotov cocktails to be made.

But, I'm not sure what it would be a roll call for, skill-wise, to use the Molotov - such as weapons, guns (as projectile weapon bows do also fall in this), or even athletics because it's being thrown.

Is there a rule clarification I've missed which could clear up which is to be rolled? Or is it GM discretion?

Comment: To clarify, you're worried about the character both being able to 'activate' (assemble and light) a Molotov and throw it as an attack?

Comment: @Ifusaso yes, sorry if I wasn't as clear as I should have been!

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to make sure. I'll try to answer this when I'm not at work for... reasons... if someone else doesn't come by before then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The weapons skill. See the core rule book.

> Weapons(Stunts, page 156)Weapons is the skill of fighting with tools: swords, knives, axes, clubs, whips, etc. (except guns—that’s a whole section of its own; see page 131). The exact weapon is more a choice of style than anything else, as this covers everything from fencing to a brawl using broken bottles and chair legs. Characters with a high Weapons skill are familiar with a variety of “old school” weapons and wield them with deadly accuracy. They include swordsmen, circus performers, and Special Forces soldiers.

-p144

This is confirmed elsewhere by a stunt, which notes thrown weapons, grenades, use weapons.

> Hand-Eye Coordination: Shooting and throwing aren’t all that different, once you get familiar with ‘em. You may use the Guns skill instead of Weapons to throw manual projectiles (rocks, grenades, boomerangs).

-p153

Acquiring said weapons is up to you, of course.